# how to optimize a search algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, spelling

so basically what i mean here is how do i make a search tool(like to search through a series of Strings, perhaps in an array or an arraylist, etc) that would be **useful**? not necessarily fast, but useful.

for example, how easy would it be to incorporate "autocorrect" where the term you're searching for yields results that are **similar** in spelling but not exact? or results that match the first 3 characters but not the whole word, or results that may **include** the word but are not necessarily comprised of the entire word? is there an API for this or a class or is there an algorithm that would help me out here?

Comment: Look into Lucene/Solr/ElasticSearch. Search is a ***big*** topic.

Comment: so this is both a very open-ended and a very opinion-oriented question. Both are off-topic here.

Comment: You will need to do a bit of your own research first, and then come back

Comment: Lucene sounds like the API you are looking for

Comment: @MarcusMüller i promise that i attempted to-- but because i'm not sure how to describe what it is im looking for i didnt really find anything helpful. either way i'm sorry for violating the rules. and thank you to cricket_007 and Matt Ball.

Comment: What you are describing is more or less exactly what the command line tool known as `grep` is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a nutshell, for SIMILAR strings, you can use the "Edit Distance" algorithm, that finds similarity (in fact it finds number of moves to turn one string into another, but that's a kind of similarity), and for the AUTOCOMPLETE tool, you can use "Trie" data structure, which works as a tree of chars, and as it reads the chars of the current word, it stops in a node that shows you where alse it can go to get to existent words.
To SEARCH something that includes the word (string), I suppose you can use KMP algorithm (or Aho-Corasick, if you wish to search for more than one word within the whole text).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Comment: reimplementing such a big tool as big data search/pattern matching might end up being a nightmare, and probably it is still better to resort to some standard libraries for such purposes, such as apache lucene